# How can we get index of a WebElement (from a list) passed in a function?

Tags: java, selenium

```
List<WebElement> deleteBtn = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='btn']//div[@class='deleteUsers']"));

public void clickDeleteBtn(WebElement element) {
    element.click();
    /* Here I want to retrieve the index of the element passed in the function */
}

main() {
    clickDeleteBtn(deleteBtn.get(5));
}
```

Suppose the findElements() above gives me a list of **10 WebElements** and I pass **element indexed 5** in clickDeleteBtn(). How, in the function, can I get the index of the element passed in?

I have tried **element.toString()** but it only gives me:
Element: [[ChromeDriver: chrome on WINDOWS (f4f6be3ed1e2a964a2dc8f0d848d3e87)] -> xpath: //div[@class='btn']//div[@class='deleteUsers']]
No information about the index of the element suggested.

I'd really appreciate your advice! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebElement itself doesn't know his index inside a list you stored it in.
The only way to know the index of given WebElement object is to iterate over the list of elements and compare the given WebElement against the current WebElement in the list, as following:

```java
WebElement element = unknownWebElement;
List<WebElement> list = entireListOfWebElements;
for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
    if(element = list.get(i)){
        return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Prophet. It seems this is the only way to go.

Comment: Nice to hear that almost a year after that 

Comment: Hahaha I was about to thank you right after you had answered but then the electricity went out and so I completely forgot about that 